# how do you know which items contained in the IN clause that were not found?

Tags: sql, oracle, select, subquery, in-clause

I have a list with 10 items on my IN clause, in my SELECT only 8 items were found.
how do you know which items contained in the IN clause were not found?

`SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE ID IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)`

My table is :

```
**ID   NAME** 
------------------
1    JOAO 

2    JOSE

3    WILLIAM

4    MARIA

5    CARLOS

6    BENJAMIN

7    DANIELLE

9    VERA

11   JOAQUIM
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to know what items listed in the `IN` clause did not find a match in the table, you could take advantage of a user-defined or built-in collection - nested table or variable array. The example below uses built-in collection `sys.odcinumberlist()` elements of which are of number data type:

```
/*sample of data */ 
with t1(col) as(
   select level
     from dual
  connect by level <= 11
 )

 select s.column_value as missing_val
   from t1      /* here you list the elements as you would using IN clause*/
  right join table(sys.odcinumberlist(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10, 70)) s
     on (t1.col = s.column_value)
  where t1.col is null
```

Result:

```
MISSING_VAL
------------
          70
```

if elements in your list are of `varchar` data type, the `OdciVarchar2List()` collection can be used or `ODCIDateList()` for elements of `date` data type. You also free to create your own SQL type collection. For example:

```
create or replace type T_Type_Name is table of number
```